# Not able to 'numpy.float64' to int in python

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point

I am trying to convert `'numpy.float64'` to `float` to do this:

[image]

```
ax.get_ylim()[0].astype(float)
```

Which prints out `-2.25`

But when I check with `type(ax.get_ylim()[0].astype(float))` it is printing out `numpy.float64`. Why is it not changing the data type?

Comment: Using Python numeric type for `dtype.astype`, numpy will automatically find the closest `dtype` for conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try the following:

```
float(ax.get_ylim()[0])
```